# Tuckey UrlRewrite: know which rules were triggered on a given request

Tags: java, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'd like to know if there's a way (out-of-the-box or not) to know which rules were triggered for a given request.
We have a webapp which generates a urlrewrite config based on various inputs (business/technical/etc.) and those can amount to more or less 2000 rules.
You can imagine that sometimes it gets hard to decipher the generated config and work out which rules were effectively triggered.

if you have any idea on how to achieve this, please chime in!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "set" tag to set a request attribute value for each of your rules and then get the request attribute out later to see which rule applied.  Something like:

```
<rule>
  ...
  <set name="ruleName">My Rule Name</set>
</rule>
```

See http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html for more documentation.

Copying my below comment into my response, you can also set response headers if you want to read these out at runtime:

```
<rule>
  ...
  <set type="response-header" name="ruleName">My Rule Name</set>
</rule>
```

Comment: yes. I thought of something along those lines. concatenate the rule id in a request attribute and output it as an http header at the end of the chain. too bad it doesn't provide something out of the box for this. logging is not an option because it doesn't provide an easy way to differentiate different request. thanks!

Comment: Hmm...  You can set a response-header out of the box.  Can't you just set a different response-header for each rule?

Comment: that would make a lot of sense. thanks. didn't think about that :)